# Installing ddt on Ubuntu with Python 3

Tags: selenium, python

I am working on a Ubuntu system which has both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 installed. I was trying to install the `ddt` library for creating data driven test cases. However when I try installing using `pip`:

```
pip install ddt
```

I get the following error :

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files 
pycompile=self.pycompile,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber os.makedirs(destsubdir)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ddt-1.0.0.dist-info'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/rahul/.pip/pip.log
```

The second last line points me in the direction that `pip` is trying to install `ddt` for Python 2.7, which I don't want.

How do I install `ddt` for Python 3.4?

Comment: There will be two versions of pip on your system, one for 2.7 and one for 3.4. It sounds like the 2.7 version is being used, probably through a symlink somewhere on your path. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2812520/3376926.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose this is what I needed at that time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I corrected this was to manually copy the `ddt` files from

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

to

`/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages`

Copied the following two files :

`ddt.py`

`ddt.pyc`

and the directory

`ddt-1.0.0.dist-info`

If any body could come up with a better solution, then please add your answer. It would be more than welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have used the *`pip3` executable instead*:

```
pip3 install ddt
```

(might require sudo).

Comment: This one works but at that time I was not aware of pip3. Although your answer works too.